# BindingResult does not get message from .properties file and not showig in jsp

Tags: java, spring, jsp, bean-validation

I use **BindingResult** to validate jsp form, Im using **message.properties** file to set all the validation message. When I print the result, it shows , there are some errors in *console*, but not showing the correct message which is in message.properties file and not even showing errors in jsp file.

Do I need to include anyannotation in controller class to get data from message.properties ?

**Configuration**

```
//other annotations
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter{

//other stuffs
 @Bean
    public MessageSource messageSource() {
        ResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ResourceBundleMessageSource();
        messageSource.setBasename("messages");
        return messageSource;
    }
}
```

**message.properties**

```
Size.companyForm.companyName= size is invalid.
```

**Model class**

```
public class Company {
    //other stuffs
    @Size(min=2,max=30)
    private String companyName;
}
```

**Company controller**

```
@RequestMapping("/add")
    public ModelAndView addCompany(Model modelAttr) {       

        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("addCompanyTiles");
        model.addObject("companyForm", new Company());
        return model;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/save", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView saveCompany(@ModelAttribute("companyForm") @Valid Company company, BindingResult result) {

        if(result.hasErrors()){
            System.out.println("Errors : "+result.toString());
            return new ModelAndView("redirect:/company/add");
        }
        companyService.saveOrUpdate(company);
        return new ModelAndView("redirect:/company/list");
    }
```

***Here error showing in console*** when I use *System.out.println("Errors :"+result.toString());*

```
Field error in object 'companyForm' on field 'companyName': rejected value []; codes [Size.companyForm.companyName,Size.companyName,Size.java.lang.String,Size]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [companyForm.companyName,companyName]; arguments []; default message [companyName],30,2]; default message [size must be between 2 and 30]
```

**jsp file**

```
   <form:form action="${saveURL} " modelAttribute="companyForm">

        // For easiness, I deleted other fields and styles
        <form:input path="companyName"/>
            <form:errors path="companyName" class="help-inline" />
    </form:form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider writing a validator for that form, then you can easily suply any text you require, e.g.

```
private void validatePhone(final String phone, final Errors errors) {
        if (StringUtils.isEmpty(phone)) {
            errors.rejectValue("phoneNumber", "error.field.required");
            return;
        }
        if (isNumber(phone)) {
            validateLength(phone, errors, "phoneNumber", 9);
        } else {
            errors.rejectValue("phoneNumber", "error.only.numbers");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I know that I am too late for this answer, but still if in case it helps any person in need.
I can see your file name is little incorrect.

**Resolution:** I think it will work if you try changing your properties file name to **messages.properties** instead of **message.properties**. just append **"s"**. Thank you :) !!

[image]